# Problem in reading dependency file when running a launch file from from boot

Tags: 20.04, ros

there
i'm using ROS Noetic with Apriltag_ros package, problem is with usb_cam-test.launch file that belongs to usb_cam package, all launch files work fine until i run them in terminal but when i try to run these launch file on boot by putting a launch file in **rc.local file. /usb_cam/camera_info is not able to read head_camera.yaml file** that present in the .ros directory in camera_info folder. (camera_info is a directory contain head_camera.yaml file is genrated at the time camera callibration with usb_cam package provided by ros)
all other launch files launched succesfully.
the launch command i'm using is:

> roslaunch usb_cam usb_cam-test.launch

i'm using ubuntu 20.04 version

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details.